# Как передать запрос в формате form-data

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, formdata

Копаюсь в одних доках, там сказанно, что запрос необходимо передавать обязательно в формате form-data.

1. form-data - это тоже самое что multipart/form-data? (тобеж просто передача без кодировки) или что то другое?
2. Приведите пожалуйста простенький пример запроса на python с использованием requests, где бы мы явно указывали формат form-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, `form-data` == `multipart/form-data`.
2. Пример кода:

```py
import requests

multipart_form_data = {
    'argument_1': (None, 'value 1'),
    'argument_2': (None, 'value 2')
}

requests.post('https://example.com/', files=multipart_form_data)
```

Comment: Понял, а без передачи файлов никак? Просто в хедере указать каком-нибудь? Мне файл передавать не требуется.

Comment: @Spartak обновил ответ.

Comment: Но в первом варианте тем же уже не multipart/form-data идти будет. Беда в том, что мне нужен multipart/form-data, но передавать файлы не нужно.

Comment: @Spartak UPDv2.